# Weird PHP error on server

Tags: php

All of a sudden, my SMF powered forum has stopped working.

In fact, PHP files no longer seem to want to open on my website.  I tried uploading a blank PHP file with just a few characters of text, and it refuses to open giving the error below.

I also tried a PHPinfo file, which didnt work, giving the same error.   Other sites on the same server are working.

```
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/users/a/n/mysite/www/index1.php' (include_path='.') in Unknown on line 0
```

Any ideas about whats gone wrong?

Comment: Maybe a problem introduced into the htaccess file in the same folder?

Comment: Check auto_prepend_file option in php.ini. It can be set by .htaccess, too. Check for existence of the `.user.ini` in the folder - it might work as php.ini per directory.

Comment: Good idea, halfer.  I've recently seen a rash of infections on servers where the hackers have actually modified the .htaccess file with redirects, etc.

Comment: Also check your apache logs. You may find something there that would point you and us to a direction.

Comment: hey. its not a .htaccess problem by the looks of it.  I will check the apache logs and php.ini too

Comment: while checking the php.ini file take a look at  `include_path` and if it's commented out or with the proper path.

Comment: `in Unknown on line 0` -> that's dynamically invoked code (eval'd or startup code). Check your PHP configuration files. For a starter you could place a blank file as `index1.php`.

Comment: Another question - does `/home/users/a/n/mysite/www/index1.php` actually exist and if so are you sure you got the right permissions? The right ones are 755 (on some hostings it's 644)

Comment: from the looks of it, you are on a shared host and probably your host messed up something, while updating etc.

Comment: I can access .TXT and .HTML files, but not .PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea. As it happens to all php files that could to what i know only mean 2 things.

Either there is somekind of error on the php extension.

OR what it most likely is, is that SMF uses a .htaccess to make user friendly links. Which means all requests to the server no matter what (Unless specified in the .htaccess) will be sent to index.php and then be handled.

So if there is a error in the index.php or the library of some sort it would explain why no matter what php file you're looking at it gives the error.

-

One thing you could do is to take a backup of all your images in the system. Then try to install a fresh version on your local machine. Once done copy/past the images back and copy all the current php files for SMF and replace the current ones on your host with them.

-

Haven't used SMF much so I'm not sure this is the solution at all. But to me it sounds like a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have broken your root document.

do chmod 755 index1.php

and it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the php.ini or php5.ini file. I don't believe the single ticks around '.' for the include_path are valid. Double quotes will work however.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have been hacked:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-unknown-failed-opening-required-google_verifyphp

Answer (score -1):

Ahh sorry reread the question. I guess this is what you may try.

Check your file permissions. by default if your web server can not read files thats what you are going to get. I could be wrong but worth having a look

so just chmod your root folder to say 755 atleast

Comment: `deny from all` is NOT related to the OP's situation. PHP does not check that rule.

Comment: `deny from all` would not generate a fatal error in php. It would generate error 500 which would be coming from the server. He is able to connect to the server - it's the php engine that throws the error.

Comment: yeah guys re-read the question. I guess its something to do with file permissions

Comment: `do with file permissions`, but not with the restriction to the apache, which is `deny from all`. The error message is generated during the run of php engine.

Comment: Agreed Cheery! PHP can only work if it does find files considering path to files is valid and are accessible to php engine.